# How to apply the conditional formatting to multiple columns using excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I created a conditional formatting to change the color based on value compare for one cell, but I don't know how to apply this formatting for the whole column and even other columns? (do I have to use for loop to set the formatting for all the cells?)

```
'add conditionalFormating for one cell.
 Set rngCell = Cells(6, 7)
 Set objCF = rngCell.FormatConditions.Add _
            (Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=" & rngCell.Address & " > " & rngCell.offset(, -3).Address)
'set formats for new CF

With objCF
    .Font.ColorIndex = 26
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End With
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try recording a macro ;)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. it only record the following script:<br>Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub

Comment: Just Curious. Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: How are you recording the macro? I just tested in Excel 2007 and 2010 and it records the macro perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel 2007/2010 don't have as extensive a macro record function as earlier versions

If you are referencing other cells when applying conditional formatting, a good method is to apply it to one cell (which you know how to do), and then copy the formatting to the rest of the column; if you are filling down a column, this should not cause you to lose other cell formats you may wish to keep

So I would start your code with

```
rngCell.FormatConditions.Delete
```

Then once the format is added, you can simply use:

```
rngCell.Copy
rngOut.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

, where rngOut is defined as starting with rngCell and filling down to the last row in the table

To apply to other columns, you would probably need a different formula as there are different offsets. To minimise the required code, you could always manually add the full set of formats/conditional formats you want to a hidden row just above the table's headers. Then you can copy all of these to your table using code of the form...

```
Range("A1:J1").Copy
Range("A3:J100").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

...if we assume your header gets pushed down to row 2 when you add the formatted row in row 1

Although I have referred to cell addresses in the above example, I would always recommend referring to range names and using cells notation e.g. Range("A1") is Cells(1, 1). The use of range names to define columns in tables is covered in more detail in this [expert Excel video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/vba-ranges-rows-columns.php). The benefits are immense...if your header row is defined with a range name, you can insert a new row above your table without having to re-write any code

Comment: Excellent and professional answer! now I can apply this conditional formatting to the whole column.

Comment: I have another question, do you know how to implement the formatConditions to change the cell color according to the cell value in another cell. my previous formatCondtions is not very correct, and I know I need to use xsCellValue type, but don't know how to implement the rule like : Cell value > $D5